# Is there a way to keep internal drive segments unmounted while booting from external device

Tags: mac, startup, macos, mount

For forensic imaging of drives and/or segments with a native Mac application, I'm booting from external device (usb, hdd, etc.) into BaseSystem. I want to keep the internal drives and/or segments unmounted during the boot process. Later will disable disk arbitration, mount these drives/segments and image them. Since the drives should be kept unmounted, there is no way of knowing drive/segment volume names and/or UUID.

I've created a deamon (System/Library/LaunchDeamons) for mount blocking (on external boot device), but it only blocks newly attached devices, not internal ones.

Also, I've also tried disabling "diskarbitrationd" daemon (desperately, on external boot device), but not worked.

Note: I've created boot image from BaseSystem.dmg of Sierra (10.12.1), and modified the contents.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Nobody even commented. There may be a solution from a clue keyword  *autodiskmount*

Comment: I guess you were the first person to raise this. For the benefit of the second, third etc - what was the solution?

Comment: I assume that you are referring to adding an entry to `/etc/fstab` to disable auto-mounting of specific partitions. Would be great if you could add a sample.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150610/how-to-prevent-all-usb-mass-storages-from-mounting-at-boot might give some clues

Comment: @patrix, that's not the solution. We don't know the drive/segment volume names and/or UUIDs beforehand.

Comment: @John, of course, but those two negative vote should go first. Because I spent too much time to figure it out. If the people given those votes were following this question, why nobody voted for the question?  Come here and vote for unuseful...!

Comment: Three now. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: The only way to get upvotes is by providing helpful answers (or editing an answer to make it more helpful).